# Specific columns

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I've been doing some stuff with HTML and I need to have a few columns. I know how to make them and the basics of how they work. However, there is a certain problem that I have. I need to have 3 columns that have an image on top, then text on bottom. However, the text on bottom can't flow into the next column if the browser is resized - it just needs to go up or down. What I have so far:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: times, serif;
  color: black;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  margin: 50px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="first">
    <img src="Images/australia_flag.jpg" alt="Australian Flag" title="Australian Flag" height="200" width="300"> text as well </div>
  <div class="second">
    <img src="Images/brazil_flag.jpg" alt="Brazilian Flag" title="Brazilian Flag"> even more text </div>
  <div class="third">
    <img src="Images/china_flag.jpg" alt="Chinese Flag" title="Chinese Flag" height="200" width="300"> text again
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure if you mean columns or rows?  Based on your code, it looks like rows.  If that's the case, I'm not sure what you mean by "flow into the next column"?  You might check out the relative and absolute values for [CSS position](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

If, in fact, you do actually mean columns, I'd strongly advise using [Bootstrap's Grid System](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp).  This is great for creating responsive columns.

Comment: I disagree. Using Bootstrap is not always the best solution and actually _shouldn't_ be the solution every time one need to align things. This could be done in a few line of code without the need of 10k of a grid system (if customized to the bare minimum)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this simple 3 column layout with a full width content area on top and  bottom here: https://jsfiddle.net/7drfva0o/2/

```
.top, .bottom {
  width:98%;
  padding:1%;
  background-color: red;
  clear:both;
}
.cols {
  width:31%;
  padding:1%;
  float:left;
  background-color:blue;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to improve your markup: having images and texts as DOM node to be "flexed"

**HTML markup improved**

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="column">
          <img src="..." />
          <p>text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column">
          <img src="..." />
          <p>text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column">
          <img src="..." />
          <p>text</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then, each of your `div` is going to have `display: flex` + `flex-direction: column` to allow the image going on top and the text going below. You will be able to adjust margin or whatever. At the minimum, I'd go like this:

**CSS improved**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Wrapped altogether, here is a snippet of what I think you're trying to achieve

**Snippet**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300x200" />
    <p>text as well</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300x200" />
    <p>text as well</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300x200" />
    <p>text as well</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, feel free to play with `flexbox` properties to align, wrap, adjust alignments, etc. Great documentation on CSS-Tricks : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/